# How to use client_side_validations rails 5 with bootstrap modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to use rails client_side_validations gem with rails 5 but it just does not work, I´ve been trying to use form_with tag and also form_for.

I was trying to follow this:

https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/wiki/Bootstrap-Modal-Validationscode

In the last link it shows that the form code should produce html like this:

```
  <form data-validate="true" ...>
```

but for me it doesnt even add the data-validate attribute...

And here is my _new.html.erb code:

```
 <%= form_for @invmtoproducto, validate: true, :remote => true do |form| %>
 ...fields
 <% end %>
```

Here the _new.js.erb file for the modal:

```
$('#modalW').html("<%= j (render 'new') %>");
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$("#modalW").slideDown(350);
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
$('#modalW').focus()
})
```

So, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using the `data` tag: `<%= form_for @invmtoproducto, data: {validate: true}, :remote => true do |form| %>`. The link to the bootstrap modal validation was using the simple_form_for helper which has slightly different syntax

Comment: man! thats awesome! I didnt think about it, it works, now the attribute is added to the form html, just have to capture the moment the modal shows up and set validation on, thank you!